# Gridview not getting last row in the Excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

I wrote a code to fetch the gridview to the Excel. Everything is working fine except a row in the gridview. When i export gridview to excel, then last row doesnot includes in the excel file. When i scanned my whole code, then i found a code which is creating a problem. Here is the code :

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
cell.Text = "A";
cell.ColumnSpan = 9;
row.Controls.Add(cell);
gv.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
}
```

This code is used to add new header to the gridview of merged cells. After removing this code, everything works fine. But i need that code.

Export to excel code :

```
Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Rept" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThh_mm_ss_") + ".xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
            Controls.Add(form);
            form.Controls.Add(gvpanel);
            form.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe you fetch a certain number of rows and as there is an header the last row is missed.... maybe we need to see more code

Comment: I am Panel in which gridview is present. I am not fetching particular number of rows. Above i posted the Export to Excel code.

Comment: @bogojane: Did you copied the code from somewhere, If yes post that link too. Or let us know why are using `cell.ColumnSpan = 9;` is that to add some CSS or something else. Please specify

Comment: I just created a new header with colspan of 9 columns.

Comment: You are not creating an Excel file. You're creating an HTML file masquerading as an Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't find the solution anywhere, which makes me to provide this solution.
When you create a header row & also you need to export to excel, below code solves of missing the last row.

Create your dynamic header row using RowCreated Event.

```
    protected void Grid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridViewRow HeaderRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell1 = new TableCell();

            HeaderCell1.Text = "Solved your Issue";
            HeaderCell1.ColumnSpan = 10;
            HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell1);
            Grid.Controls[0].Controls.Add(HeaderRow);
        }
    }
```

and now you can call your ExportToExcel method:

```
      private void ExportToExcel(GridView gv, string exportfilename)
    {
        string filename = exportfilename + ".xls";

        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        gv.RenderControl(hw);
        //Write the HTML back to the browser.
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an excel spreadsheet as a data source to your GridView and connect to it like any other database:

[How To Query and Display Excel Data by Using ASP.NET, ADO.NET, and Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311731)